# Button over View in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to make Button over the View?

I have something like

```
 private BorderPane makePane(Node view) {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button leftButton = new Button();
        Button rightButton = new Button();
        Button bottomButton = new Button();

        leftButton.setOnAction(e -> goBack(pane));
        rightButton.setOnAction(e -> goNext(pane));
        bottomButton.setOnAction(e -> play());

        pane.setCenter(view);
        pane.setLeft(leftButton);
        pane.setRight(rightButton);
        pane.setBottom(bottomButton);
        return pane;
    }
```

Now, I have view on the centter and buttons on the sides. But it crops my Image or Video, depends on which instance of Node I get.

There is crop on the pane from left and right sides for each button. I don't want to see the white/black/other vertical line through whole window only for 1 button.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking for here, but: `MediaView` is non-resizeable. You may need to be able to play around with `fitWidth` and/or `fitHeight` to get it to the desired size. Furthermore `BorderPane` is not the right layout to overlay the children. Depending on the use case `StackPane` or `AnchorPane` are alternatives that allow you to position nodes at specific distances from the border of the pane possibly providing you with the desired overlay...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It doesn't matter which pane to choose. My main goal is to choose some way with overlay. About MediaView and ImageView - I do not actually know which size it would be, so I make Height and Width with `Stage.getHeight-Stage.getHeight/4`